# Can you provide any example where the closure outlives the current function?

Tags: concurrency, rust, closures

Based on the Rust book, the following code can cause the `closure may outlive the current function` error:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let x = 1;
    thread::spawn(|| {
        println!("x is {}", x);
    });
}
```

It is abstract to think when and how the closure would outlive the current function happen; can you provide any examples or specifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you moved the closure into a thread and threads may outlive the current function (they are not automatically joined an the function end, use the `crossbeam` crate for this kind of feature), it's just the same as moving it on the heap.

If you look at the following piece of code, you can see that moving a closure to the heap and returning it is forbidden. Since threads are basically the same thing with respect to borrowing, you can't reference anything in a thread.

```
fn foo() -> Box<FnOnce()> {
    let x = 1;
    Box::new(|| {
        println!("x is {}", x);
    })
}

fn main() {
    let f = foo();
}
```

Note that the compiler gives a solution to the Problem in the error message:

```
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `x` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword, as shown:
  |     Box::new(move || {
```

Comment: super effective. Thanks!

Comment: the compiler should give the `move` solution for threads aswell.